# Is it okay to start a sentence with "Doesn't matter"?

Tags: grammar, conversational-deletion

Is it okay to start a sentence with "Doesn't matter"? Like:

> Doesn't matter which train you board, you are going to be late for the meeting.

Comment: I'd go with _No matter which train you board,_ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly grammatical and perfectly common. The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) have well over a hundred cites. For example:

- > Doesn't matter if he saw his fox, he wouldn't shoot it on a Sunday.
- > Doesn't matter where you hit someone. Contact is always lethal.
- > Doesn't matter what creed or colour you are, as long as you are mad!
- > Doesn't matter where you go in this world, son, you're in.
- > Doesn't matter which one's bigger, which one's smaller, the one that has the highest interest rate is costing you the most money.
- > Doesn't matter where you turn, cause Jesus is gonna be there, just waiting for you.

Comment: But 'Doesn't matter [...]' is not a full sentence in the traditional sense. And I'd not consider the subject deletion appropriate for formal writing.

Comment: @Edwin as you well know, there are more traditional senses than there are senses. In my answer, for the sake of comprehensibility and everyone's sanity, I am obviously just running with the same definition the OP uses. The question of what we call the thing is rather irrelevant to the question of whether the thing is English. We can call it a sentence, or a fragment, or a green cat, but it is still perfectly grammatical and perfectly common, which is the sole focus of my answer.

Comment: As to formality, yes, you are correct once again, but that is another thing that the OP is not asking about. If they are interested in that aspect, they are welcome to amend their question accordingly. Failing that, I can only go by their example sentence which does not strike me as coming from an excessively formal context, either.

Comment: If one's intention is really to help OP and others reading this, it is virtually obligatory to (1) point out that the mantra 'You should only use sentences' assumes that 'sentence' is well-defined before (2a) repeating for the umpteenth time on ELU that the 'rule' is a nonsense if applied strictly and (2b) that even its most prescriptive champions will hypocritically use 'No', 'Hello', 'After the match' and 'Very well, thank you'.